# Basic auth with spring 3.2. Authorization param isn't in the header

Tags: spring, rest, authentication, spring-mvc, curl

I'm working in an application that uses spring 3,2 and consume data from a rest api that requires only basic authentication... the thing is that I can't login to the api, all I get is 401.

The configuration is the following:

First, the credentials provider

```
<bean id="credentialProvider" class="org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider" />
```

Authorization scope for accessing restful service. Since we want this template to be used for everything, we are setting up it with defaults

```
<bean id="authScope" class="org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope">
  <constructor-arg name="host"> <null /> </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg name="port"> <value>-1</value> </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg name="realm"> <null /> </constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg name="scheme"> <null /> </constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Username and Password Credentials to access the api services

```
<bean id="credentials" class="org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials">
  <constructor-arg name="userName" value="${dataApi.username}"></constructor-arg>
  <constructor-arg name="password" value="${dataApi.password}"></constructor-arg>
</bean>
```

Creating the credential provider

```
<bean id="methodInvoke" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.MethodInvokingFactoryBean">
  <property name="targetObject" ref="credentialProvider" />
  <property name="targetMethod" value="setCredentials" />
  <property name="arguments">
    <list>
      <ref local="authScope" />
      <ref local="credentials" />
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>
```

We have to use a proxy, so...

```
<bean id="proxyHttpClient" class="com.cibbva.commerce360.utils.ProxyHttpClient">
  <constructor-arg name="host" value="${proxy.hostname}" />
  <constructor-arg name="port" value="${proxy.port}" />
  <constructor-arg name="user" value="${proxy.username}" />
  <constructor-arg name="pass" value="${proxy.password}" />
  <constructor-arg name="conman" ref="clientConnectionManager"></constructor-arg>
  <property name="credentialsProvider" ref="credentialProvider" />
</bean>
```

The clientConnectionManager it's defined as:

```
<bean id="clientConnectionManager" class="org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingClientConnectionManager">
  <property name="defaultMaxPerRoute" value="${dataAPi.connection.maxPerRoute}"></property>
  <property name="maxTotal" value="${dataAPi.connection.maxTotal}"></property>
</bean>
```

And finally the requestFactory and restTemplate:

```
<bean id="requestFactory" class="org.springframework.http.client.HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory">
  <constructor-arg ref="proxyHttpClient" />
</bean>

<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate">
  <constructor-arg name="requestFactory" ref="requestFactory" />
</bean>
```

I think that the problem is because the Authorization parameter isn't being added to the header of the request, looking in debug mode, I see the following:

```
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> GET /xxxx/xxxxxx?xxxx HTTP/1.1
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Accept: application/json, application/*+json
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Host: hostname
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> Connection: Keep-Alive
DEBUG org.apache.http.headers - >> User-Agent: Apache-HttpClient/4.2.3 (java 1.5)
DEBUG org.apache.http.wire - << "HTTP/1.1 401 No Autorizado[\r][\n]"
```

As can you see, there isn't auth information in the header. To discard the possibility of wrong username and password, I use curl to make the same request:

```
curl -v --user 'username:pasword' https://xxxx/xxxxxx?xxxx
```

The output is:

```
SSL certificate verify ok.
Server auth using Basic with user 'user'
GET xxxx/xxxxxx?xxxx HTTP/1.1
Authorization: Basic Y29tL....
User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
Host: hostname
Accept: */*
HTTP/1.1 404 No Encontrado
```

To summarize, how can I add the parameter `Authorization` to the header of my request?

Thank you so much!

Comment: so when using spring, are you using https?

Comment: Yes, with spring I'm also using https

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I've finally got a solution to this problem. What I've done is create a class that implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor, and then put the Authorization Header manually, the code is something like:

```
public class RequestHeaderIntercepter implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor{

  @Override
  public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body,
    ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
    HttpRequestWrapper requestWrapper = new HttpRequestWrapper(request);
    requestWrapper.getHeaders().set("Authorization", "encoded username:password");
    return execution.execute(request, body);
  }
}
```

After that, you have to register the listener to the restTemplate and that's all! The request is intercepted and the Authorization parameter is added to the header.